# asp.net MVC: different scripts in pages

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have pretty simple landing site (index, faq, about, contact) based on ASP.net MVC. Of course, I use Layout (with head and footer), every View contains just page content. The problem: some pages has unique footer or head.

For example:
Index page has carousel (only this page, other pages has no carousel).
In source HTML (that web-designer sent me) I see scripts links in the head and scripts block in the end. Yes, I know: I can use Razor tag "@section" and declare this non-standard head and footer inside my view.

But! It means my view (page content) includes razor syntax. This is not pure HTML. What if site admin will want to edit index page - he will see Razor tags, he can't use some html editor or online tool (TinyMCE) for edit. He must know Razor. He can't just insert pure html.

Maybe I shouldn't keep page contents in DB? (but this site must support multi-lang). What is the best approac in this case?

Thanks.

Comment: i Strongly Recommend you To use Umbraco Cms it well 100% solve your problems i can help u out, and umbraco has Great Community

Comment: CMS for site with 5 pages? What is adavantage?

Comment: You have Full Control over it u Can extend it and learn umbraco for further use